# Using shift and rolling in pandas with groupBy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    list(
        zip(["A", "B", "C"],
            [np.array(["id %02d" % i for i in range(1, 11)]).repeat(10),
            pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=100).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            [i for i in range(10, 110)]])
        )
))

df = df.groupby(["A", "B"]).sum()

df["D"] = df["C"].shift(1).rolling(2).mean()

df
```

This code generates the following:

[image]

I want the rolling logic to start over for every new ID. Right now, `ID 02` is using the last two values from `ID 01` to calculate the mean.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need `groupby`:

```
df['D'] = df["C"].shift(1).groupby(df['A'], group_keys=False).rolling(2).mean()
print (df.head(20))
                   C     D
A     B                   
id 01 2018-01-01  10   NaN
      2018-01-02  11   NaN
      2018-01-03  12  10.5
      2018-01-04  13  11.5
      2018-01-05  14  12.5
      2018-01-06  15  13.5
      2018-01-07  16  14.5
      2018-01-08  17  15.5
      2018-01-09  18  16.5
      2018-01-10  19  17.5
id 02 2018-01-11  20   NaN
      2018-01-12  21  19.5
      2018-01-13  22  20.5
      2018-01-14  23  21.5
      2018-01-15  24  22.5
      2018-01-16  25  23.5
      2018-01-17  26  24.5
      2018-01-18  27  25.5
      2018-01-19  28  26.5
      2018-01-20  29  27.5
```

Or:

```
df['D'] = df["C"].groupby(df['A']).shift(1).rolling(2).mean()
print (df.head(20))
                   C     D
A     B                   
id 01 2018-01-01  10   NaN
      2018-01-02  11   NaN
      2018-01-03  12  10.5
      2018-01-04  13  11.5
      2018-01-05  14  12.5
      2018-01-06  15  13.5
      2018-01-07  16  14.5
      2018-01-08  17  15.5
      2018-01-09  18  16.5
      2018-01-10  19  17.5
id 02 2018-01-11  20   NaN
      2018-01-12  21   NaN
      2018-01-13  22  20.5
      2018-01-14  23  21.5
      2018-01-15  24  22.5
      2018-01-16  25  23.5
      2018-01-17  26  24.5
      2018-01-18  27  25.5
      2018-01-19  28  26.5
      2018-01-20  29  27.5
```

Comment: I tested without `group_keys=False` argument now, and it still works. Do I really need this?

Comment: I add it because get `NaN`s in first solution, but if working nice, be free omit it.

Comment: @Nilzone- Tested for second solution, for me it working nice if omitted.

Comment: Yeah - it looks like it doesn't affect the result in this case at least :)

Comment: How can this work? `df['D']` indexes df to a pandas.Series (column D of df), so, the subsequent `groupby('A')` would fail due it to not having a column named 'A'.

Comment: @pablete - Change `A` to `df['A']`

Comment: @jezrael I found that your solution doesn't work negative periods of shift method (at least partially). In the original question the period is positive, still for the full picture I feel that correct option for negative periods should be added. Please see my answer

Answer (score 5):

While the accepted answer by @jezrael works correctly for positive shifts, it gives incorrect result (partially) for negative shifts. Please check the following

```
df['D'] = df["C"].groupby(df['A']).shift(1).rolling(2).mean()
df['E'] = df["C"].groupby(df['A']).rolling(2).mean().shift(1).values
df['F'] = df["C"].groupby(df['A']).shift(-1).rolling(2).mean()
df['G'] = df["C"].groupby(df['A']).rolling(2).mean().shift(-1).values
df.set_index(['A', 'B'], inplace=True)
print(df.head(20))

                   C     D     E     F     G
A     B                                     
id 01 2018-01-01  10   NaN   NaN   NaN  10.5
      2018-01-02  11   NaN   NaN  11.5  11.5
      2018-01-03  12  10.5  10.5  12.5  12.5
      2018-01-04  13  11.5  11.5  13.5  13.5
      2018-01-05  14  12.5  12.5  14.5  14.5
      2018-01-06  15  13.5  13.5  15.5  15.5
      2018-01-07  16  14.5  14.5  16.5  16.5
      2018-01-08  17  15.5  15.5  17.5  17.5
      2018-01-09  18  16.5  16.5  18.5  18.5
      2018-01-10  19  17.5  17.5   NaN   NaN
id 02 2018-01-11  20   NaN  18.5   NaN  20.5
      2018-01-12  21   NaN   NaN  21.5  21.5
      2018-01-13  22  20.5  20.5  22.5  22.5
      2018-01-14  23  21.5  21.5  23.5  23.5
      2018-01-15  24  22.5  22.5  24.5  24.5
      2018-01-16  25  23.5  23.5  25.5  25.5
      2018-01-17  26  24.5  24.5  26.5  26.5
      2018-01-18  27  25.5  25.5  27.5  27.5
      2018-01-19  28  26.5  26.5  28.5  28.5
      2018-01-20  29  27.5  27.5   NaN   NaN
```

Note that columns `D` and `E` are computed for `.shift(1)` and columns `F` and `G` are computed for `.shift(-1)`. Column `E` is incorrect, since the first value of `id 02` uses last two values of `id 01`. Column `F` is incorrect since first values are `NaN`s for both `id 01` and `id 02`. Columns `D` and `G` give correct results. So, the full answer should be like this. If shift period is non-negative, use the following

```
df['D'] = df["C"].groupby(df['A']).shift(1).rolling(2).mean()
```

If shift period is negative, use the following

```
df['G'] = df["C"].groupby(df['A']).rolling(2).mean().shift(-1).values
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is helpful! It is very easy to ignore the difference!